# Macbook Air A1466 - WiFi channel 13

Tags: wifi, macbook-pro, internet

We are 5 tenants in a big house in the Netherlands and apparently channel 13 is the only one not too crowded to offer us a decent connection. Setting the router on any other channel makes the internet almost unusable for everybody. Problem is that the  cannot detect the WiFi connection whenever it is set on channel 13.

Is there anyway to get a Macbook Air to detect channel 13 on our Wifi router?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you create a 5GHz network to go along with it or is the base station you have legacy/i.e. only able to do 2.4 GHz?

Comment: Only 2.4 Ghz unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

First open you About this Mac - more Info - System Information

then look under the

WiFi

Here is what it looks in my place in Spain.

[image: WiFi location]

The Ch 1..13 are on 2.4 GHz and the 36...140 are on 5GHz, if your router supports it switch to 5 GHz and you will be lonely there (almost)

If not possible to use 5GHz - (router limitation)

Take Note of

Locale and Country Code (those need to changed to see the Ch 13)

Next check your router settings for Location/Country Code.

The country code of your router is whichever one it was legally purchased for use in. See if it can be changed.

Comment: Check locale. Europe has more channels than the US, so with a US setup, channel 13 is not visible.

Comment: Note that channels are limited by laws in some places so as some frequencies are used for other purposes

Answer (score 0):

When set on auto my router frequently used 13 because it was not used by the surrounding routers (from other buildings), so sometimes it was visible by the MacBook Air and sometimes disappeared - which was not a problem when I switched to 5G. The same thing happened with my Kindle PaperWhite that couldn't see 5G. The simple solution was to use 5G for all appliances that could use it and to switch the router to a 2.4 channel that can be seen by US-made stuff - I switched to 10 just to be sure!

Writing from UK.